# Generating data from a Beta-Binomial distribution by inverting CDF in R

Tags: r, sampling, random-generation, cumulative-distribution-function, beta-binomial-distribution

I am trying to generate data from a beta-binomial distribution by inverting its cdf in R.

The code I have written to calculate the cdf seems to be working fine for most cases, but gives me values like 1.46 for the right-most support when alpha and beta are small. ( a and b are the alpha and beta parameters of the beta-binomial distribution):

```
cbetabin <- function(a,b,n,k){

    sum <- 0

    for (i in 0:k){
            b <- choose(n,i)*(beta(i+a,n-i+b)/beta(a,b))
            sum <- sum + b
    }

    return(sum)

}
```

Here's some sample output:

```
> res <- cbetabin(0.2,0.25,10,10)
> res
[1] 1.466977
```

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong here.

If it helps I also printed out the values of the pdf calculated by the function.

```
[1] 3.435193e-01 8.512258e-02 2.619279e-02 8.476199e-03 2.779507e-03
[6] 9.455368e-04 3.518647e-04 1.551412e-04 9.244767e-05 1.004164e-04
[11] 9.992411e-01
```

Thanks.

Comment: This appears to be a pure coding issue, which would generally be regarded as off topic here. Please see the [help/on-topic] in particular the section related to programming; you might be able to make it on topic at stackoverflow perhaps (see their own [on-topic help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), in which case edit this as needed and then flag for migration. Alternatively, if you can rephrase it to a more general question about the approach to solving the underlying statistics problem, it might be more clearly on topic here. This will likely be closed is left as it stands.

Answer (score 2):

You have a simple implementation error.  You are overwriting the input parameter b within your for loop.  The following ought to do the trick:

```
cbetabin <- function(a,b,n,k){

    sum <- 0

    for (i in 0:k){
            summand <- choose(n,i)*(beta(i+a,n-i+b)/beta(a,b))
            sum <- sum + summand
    }

    return(sum)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b <- choose(n,i)*(beta(i+a,n-i+b)/beta(a,b))
```

Every time it generate a new 'b', it will use the new value of b to calculate beta() in the next loop.  Don't use b, change it into any other letter, such as:

```
...    
t <- choose(n,i)*(beta(i+a,n-i+b)/beta(a,b))
sum <- sum + t
...
```